# Equation in which a sofa foam needs to be bent according to a chamfer.

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

Good morning guys!

I need an equation in which a sofa foam needs to be bent according to a chamfer.

The idea behind the equation is to find out, according to the angle of the chamfer and distance, what is the curve in the fold of the foam.

If you have any questions, I'm happy to help!

As per reference the drawing:

[image]

Comment: That probably depends also on material properties of the sofa foam. E.g. will the foam compress and bulge up near the sharp interior corner and might it stretch and perhaps tear along the round edge? Or can one ignore that?

Comment: Why is the lower half of face A vertical in the partially folded picture?